# code is not calling in time interval

Tags: jquery

I want to call a jquery code in every 5 sec interval for that i am using following code
but this code is not calling in repeatedly

My code is

```
 setInterval($.getJSON('friendshipRequestCount', function(data) {
        var cnt=data.totalFriendshipRequestCount;
        if(cnt>0){
            $('#f-request-count').css("display","block");
            $('#f-request-count').html(data.totalFriendshipRequestCount);
        }
        else{
            $('#f-request-count').css("display","none");
        }
    }),5000);
```

Please see what is the problem

Comment: The first argument of setInterval should be a function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`setInterval` needs to be passed a function, not the result of `getJSON`.

```
setInterval(function () {
    $.getJSON('friendshipRequestCount', function (data) {
        var cnt = data.totalFriendshipRequestCount;
        if (cnt > 0) {
            $('#f-request-count').css("display", "block");
            $('#f-request-count').html(data.totalFriendshipRequestCount);
        } else {
            $('#f-request-count').css("display", "none");
        }
    });
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 2):

Pass a function as first parameter in setInterval. `$.getJSON` returns a [jqXHR](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#jqXHR)

```
setInterval(function () {
    $.getJSON('friendshipRequestCount', function(data) {
        var cnt=data.totalFriendshipRequestCount;
        if(cnt>0){
            $('#f-request-count').css("display","block");
            $('#f-request-count').html(data.totalFriendshipRequestCount);
        }
        else{
            $('#f-request-count').css("display","none");
        }
    });
}, 5000);
```

Comment: There's a missing closing parenthesis after the handler passed to `getJSON`, and an extra one after the first argument to `setInterval`.

Comment: @Asad Thank you for catching it!